# Symfony2 Form collection Could not load type CollectionType

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms

I am trying build a form using symfony2 form CollectionType With onetoMany relationship in between two entities. But it always end with Invalid argument exception Could not load type "Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType".
I have Two entities called Ticket and Attachment. A ticket has many attachments and each attachment relates to single ticket.

In Tickets Entity :

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Attachment", mappedBy="ticket", fetch="EXTRA_LAZY", cascade={"persist"})
 */
private $attachments;
```

And in Attachment Entity :

```
/**
 * @var integer
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Ticket", inversedBy="attachments", fetch="LAZY")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="ticket_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $ticket;
```

AttachmentType Form :

```
/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('name')
        ->add('file')
    ;
}

/**
 * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
 */
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'Attachment'
    ));
}
```

TicketType Form :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $formBuilderInterface, array $options){
    $formBuilderInterface
        ->add("subject", "text", array(
                "label"=>"RaiseTicketType.labels.subject.label",
                "attr" => array(
                    "class" => "ui-flat",
                    "placeholder"=>"RaiseTicketType.labels.subject.label"
                )
            )
        )
        ->add("attachments", CollectionType::class, array(
                'entry_type' => AttachmentType::class,
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true
            )
        );
    ;
}

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $optionsResolverInterface){
    $optionsResolverInterface->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'Ticket'
    ));
}
```

I have already import the CollectionType namespace

Comment: Need to user the fully qualified class names for data_class: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#creating-form-classes

Answer (score 3):

The above implementation is for the latest version of the symfony (3.0) and here is implementation for the symfony version older than 3.0. Just need to replace the attachment field with

```
->add("attachments", "collection", array(
                'type' => new AttachmentType(),
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'by_reference' => false
            )
        );
```

Comment: Please note that it is a bad idea to pass form type instances to `type` attribute of the collection type. The thing with this solution is, that for every embedded type, Symfony then has to resolve the form type again which can have real performance impact. Instead, before Symfony 2.8, you should [register your form type as a service](http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/book/forms.html#defining-your-forms-as-services) and pass the name used for that alias instead.